# Recover original timestamp after command line copy

Tags: macos, unix

Is it possible to recover the original time stamp (date added, date modified) of files after copying them (command line, cp -r folder) The original files are gone.

Comment: I'm going to say no. But why do you need the original timestamp?

Comment: Thx - Audacity audio recovery problem - for obscured reasons audacity temp file chunks are not named in alphanumeric order ... i copied the temp folder and audacity deleted the content of it later on ... so i have only the copied temp files and need to sort them according to their time stamp

Comment: Not helpful now, but in the future consider using the archive option: `cp -a`.

Answer (score 0):

On some Unix-based systems you can say

> `touch –r` *file<sub>1</sub>   file<sub>2</sub>*

to set the modification time of *file<sub>2</sub>* to that of *file<sub>1</sub>*. 
(In this case `-r` stands for *reference*, I believe.) 
If you copied an entire directory, as in `cp -r old new`, then try

```
cd old
find . –exec touch -r {} ../new/{}
```

Proceed with care; I haven’t tested this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cp -p flag.

`-p    Cause cp to preserve the following attributes of each source file in the copy: modification time, access time, file flags, file mode, user ID, and group ID, as allowed by permissions.`